# 2010s (?) anime in which a girl trains to drive an alien battleship; her mother works in alien surveillance

Tags: story-identification, anime

A couple years ago I watched an anime on Netflix, maybe 2015-2017...

It was about a girl whose mom I think worked at some government or intergalactic facility that kept an eye on aliens (who looked like regular people but just weren’t living on Earth).

The girl she works at maybe one of her family members cafe or restaurant on the beach. But she goes onto the site for some reason, and is prepared to be using one of their small battleships which apparently is an alien ship who only accepts a certain type of person, I think.

And it accepts her and so she learns how to do it, practicing and one day she has to fight other people and save her friends. Another girl, and maybe three guys on one big ship.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that it might be *Kuromukuro*.

A highschool girl (Yukina) activates a mech at her mother's work.

The mother works at an UN research facility.

Earth is attacked by mechas controlled by human looking aliens.

It's from 2016, and on netflix.

> 60 years ago, the Black Relic is unearthed during the construction of the Kurobe Dam. In the present day, the United Nations is researching it when the Efy Dolgh return. Yukina Shirahane, daughter of the UN facility director, accidentally reactivates the cockpit module of Kuromukuro, releasing Kennosuke from cryostasis. Aided by Yukina's family and the UN in adjusting to life in the 21st century, he stands against Efy Dolgh's invasion of Earth just as he did in his home era. As the Black Relic is the most effective weapon the UN has against Efy Dolgh technology, Kennosuke becomes one of their most valuable assets. Due to an accident, Yukina is biometrically synchronized with the Black Relic, and as it requires two pilots, Yukina thus becomes Ouma's combat partner.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia, *Kuromukuro*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuromukuro)</sub>

One thing that plays a central part in Kuromukuro though, that you do not mention, is that the mech Yukina activates already contains a boy, who has been in stasis for 450 years. The mech only functions at 100% when they work together to control it. Also she looks exactly like a princess the boy in stasis used to protect back in his own time.

Comment: I've formatted the link so it reads better than just the plain one. You can do so like: `[link text](link)`.

Comment: Thank you, I will be sure to keep that in mind in the future.